# Change innerhtml of each first column in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the `innerHTML` of each column in each row, but I cant get it to work properly.

```js
 var numOfRows = $('.wrap').children('.row').length;
 for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
   var $firstDiv = $(".input_fields_wrap .row:eq(0)");
   $firstDiv.text("Works");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I properly go about this and change the `innerHTML` of each column in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, too:

```
$('.row').each(function(i) {
$(this).children().first().text('changed '+i);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c1hcL26m/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector

> Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

To use index, You can use [`.text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)/[`.html(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

```
$('.wrap .row .col-md-4:first-child').text(function(i) {
  return 'Changed Text: ' + (i+1);
});
```

```js
$('.wrap .row .col-md-4:first-child').text(function(i) {
  return 'Changed Text: ' + (i+1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how would i count them i want to change the text to something like, CHANGED1, CHANGED2, CHANGED3,... ?

Comment: @mheonyae, Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Please do like bellow.

```
$( ".row div:first-child").text("Some text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop on your `.row` and find the first div and change the text. use the below logic

```
$(".wrap .row").each(function(i){
  $(this).find('div:eq(0)').text("Changed "+ i );     
});
```

Here is a working snippet

```js
$(".wrap .row").each(function(i){
  $(this).find('div:eq(0)').text("Changed "+ i );
  $(this).find('div:eq(0)').css('background-color','yellow'); //demo purpose
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      DONT CHANGE
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

I now understand OP's request is to change the content of the first column only. Using this selector pattern we are able to accurately target desired elements. The use of `.each()` allows us to iterate through each target and modify the content and give each one a unique number as well.

> ```
>  var firstCols = $('div > div > div:first-of-type')
> ```

This selector is saying:

> - Find the divs that are the first child div...
> - ...of a div (mom) and that div must...
> - ...have a div parent as well (grandma).

---

#### OLD

Each column of each row equates to all cells or with this Bootstrap layout it would mean all `div.col-md-4`. I noticed the "CHANGE" and "DONT CHANGE" pattern, is that what you really want instead?

> ```
>  $('.col-md-4').html('NEW CONTENT');
> ```

#### SNIPPET

```js
var firstCols = $('div > div > div:first-of-type');
firstCols.each(function(idx, obj) {
  $(this).html('ROW' + (idx + 1)).css('background', 'cyan');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        DONT CHANGE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript approach**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.row div:first-child').forEach(function(r){r.innerHTML = "MYchangedtext"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
 $(".wrap .row .col-md-4:first-child").text("Hello world!");
```